# Magento: Best Product type for Camera Kits

Tags: magento, product

I am developing a magento site. In this site I have products for camera kits. In one kit the product can have camera body, camera lens etc. These products when sold in group will have lesser price when sold individually.

I am thinking of "Grouped Products" in magento will suit my case the best.

But how to set the discounted price when purchased from a group?
Also I have to import product from another site so I will be creating all the products programmatically. So any suggestions for the discounted price. Also my approach for grouped products is right or wrong?

Comment: for future, you will receive more answers on magento.stackexchange.com if your question is not related to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouped products are just a way to sell multiple products on one product page.

You could use a bundle product. When creating a bundle you can choose if the price will be calculated as the sum of all items or a fixed price.

#### I see two options for you:

1. Use the fixed price and create one bundle for each camera kit. The bundle will have an option "body" and an option "lens", each option has only one product selection and is marked as "required" (i.e. you don't have a choice)
2. Use dynamic price and a special price, then you can add different body and lens selections with different prices from which the customer can choose, but can give a discount of for example 10% on the bundle.